# Local geodesics

Tags: geodesic, geometric-group-theory

Suppose I have a $K$-local geodesic in a metric space $M$, $\alpha(t) : [0,L] \rightarrow M$, meaning $$\forall t ,t' \in [0,L] \quad \text{s.t.} \quad |t-t'|\leq K, \quad |\alpha(t)-\alpha(t')|=|t-t'| $$  
and suppose I take two points $t,t' \in [0,L]$ such that $|t-t'|=2K$ , assuming t'>t and I divide the segment in the following way:
$$[\alpha(t),\alpha(t')]=[\alpha(t),\alpha(t+K)]\, \cup \,[\alpha(t+K),\alpha(t')]$$
so every part is locally geodesic. Now suppose I want to calculate $d(\alpha(t),\alpha(t'))$ I get the following:
$$d(\alpha(t),\alpha(t'))= d(\alpha(t),\alpha(t+K))+d(\alpha(t+K),\alpha(t'))=(t+K-t)+ (t'-t-K)=t'-t.$$
But the original $t,t'$ were in a distance that doesn't ensure that. In that way I shall get the same result for every $ t,t'$ such that $|t-t'|>K$.
So what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty much everything.

Start with the faulty notation $[\alpha(t),\alpha(t')]$. What can it possibly mean? Do you mean the image of **a** geodesic (there might be many!) connecting $\alpha(t), \alpha(t')$?

More importantly, the equality
$$d(\alpha(t),\alpha(t'))=d(\alpha(t),\alpha(t+K))+d(\alpha(t+K),\alpha(t'))$$
comes out of nowhere and is, in general false.

I suggest, you think of the map
$$
\alpha: [0, 2\pi]\to M=S^1\subset {\mathbb C},
$$
$$
\alpha(t)=e^{it},
$$
where $S^1$ is  equipped with the angular metric. Prove that $\alpha$ is a $\pi$-local geodesic. See where your  argument breaks down in this example.

Comment: I think I understand- it's because the length of the local geodesic can't be devided like in an actual geodesic, since $L(\alpha(t),\alpha(t'))\neq d(\alpha(t),\alpha(t'))$ . Did I get it right?

Comment: @DvirCohen: The expression "because the length of the local geodesic can't be devided like in an actual geodesic" does not make sense to me but, yes, local geodesics behave differently from geodesics.